# Брандмауэр Windows/Общий доступ к Интернету (ICS)

Tags: сеть, безопасность, сервер

Выключается служба Брандмауэр Windows/Общий доступ к Интернету (ICS),у меня сервер и на сервере эта служба когда отключается то инет есть только на сервере все остальные компы в сети могу только пользоваться локальными ресурсами без выхода в интернет,я ее включаю,проходит 2-3 минуты и служба опять выключается и так постоянно,подскажите пожалуйста что ее может выключать или как вообще без нее обойтись,очень горит!!

Comment: А смотрели в системный журнал? Там обязательно что-то должно быть про причину падения сервиса.

Comment: что то не чего не нахожу,я его включил он опять как обычно выключился но в журнале не чего так и нет,возможно не там смотрю,ну в Администрировании-Просмотр событий не чего не вижу что касалось бы хоть как то моей проблемы

Comment:  У меня та же проблема... Все тоже самое, так и не понял в чем проблема.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите на вкладке Свойства->Восстановление, возможно, у Вас в поле "Последующие сбои" стоит "Не выполнять никаких действий" вместо "Перезапуск службы".

Comment: это то я как раз и сделал,там стоит перезапуск через 1 минуту,но оно не фига не пере запускается через 1 минуты просто вырубается потом

Comment: А на вкладке "зависимости"? Возможно, сбои в работе служб "Сетевые подключения" или тому подобное, от чего зависит Ваша служба?

Comment: да моя служба зависит от Инструенатрий упралений Виндовс и Сетевіе подключения,нужно теперь найти

Comment: прошу прощение за ошибки глючная клава стоит(

Comment: Инструментарий Windows -- это базовая служба, на неё можно не смотреть. А на остальные смотрите сами. И потом, посмотрите, возможно, у Вас стоит другой брандмауэр или антивирус, который блокирует службу. Или оптимизатор...